# Chaining this promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

What's the proper way to chain something when you need to append the results to an array that is sitting at the top level of a function's scope?

```
function run() {
    let array = []

    let input = 'object'

    promiseA(input)
    .then((result) => {
        array.push(result)
    })

    promiseB(input)
    .then((result) => {
        array.push(result)
    })

    console.log(array.join(' '))
}
```

Order doesn't matter for my application, I can parallelize it if that's considered best practices. It's literally just checking for a condition, there's no async calls to get results from an API or anything like that.

Comment: Clarity needed. What do you mean by 'chain something with an array'? What is the source of `promiseA()` and `promiseB()` is that pseudo code? What have you tried.

Comment: Independently add objects to an array (normal chaining leaves the array out of scope), A and B just return a string each to be appended

Comment: _normal chaining leaves the array out of scope_ - no, it doesn't. The order of operation is different than you expect it to be.

Comment: If you chain it as `promiseA.then((resultA) => { array.push(resultA); return promiseB.then((resultB) => { array.push(resultB) })})` (which is a bad way to chain it, but whatever) it goes out of scope.

Comment: Can you create working example in Plunker or fiddle ...

Comment: @ARMATAV - I realize you've already accepted an answer, but please look at my answer. It more directly answers your question. Avoids side effects and the scope issue you mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**An alternative is using `async` function:**

This approach executes the promises one by one, that way you will be able to handle the result with the desired execution order.

```js
function promiseA(input) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      resolve(input);
    }, 1000);
  });
}

function promiseB(input) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      resolve(input);
    }, 500);
  });
}

async function run() {
  let array = [];
  
  let input = 'Ele';
  array.push(await promiseA(input));

  input = "from SO";
  array.push(await promiseB(input));

  console.log(array.join(' '))
}

console.log('Wait for 1.5sec...')
run()
```

Comment: This is more what I want, it's not as 'bulky' as Promise.All(), is this valid?  `array.push("the most recent result is: " + await promiseA(input))`

Comment: @ARMATAV Yes, it's valid.

Answer (score 2):

You should use Promise.all to wait for promise A and promise B to complete. Promise.all will receive an array of results (from each Promise) that you can then use.

You might have something like:

```
var promiseA =       doSomethingThatReturnsPromise(input);
var promiseB = doSomethingThatReturnsPromise(anotherInput);

Promise.all([promiseA, promiseB]).then(function(resultsArray) { // do something });
```

Comment: Promise.all() is not a chain. It effectively parallels the resolves.

Comment: I think the OP wants to serialize the execution.

Comment: Perhaps we need clarification. I know what Promise.All does. It seemed to fit the sample code provided but perhaps order does matter for the posted question?

Answer (score 2):

your function will look like this

```
function run () {
 return Promise.all([promiseA(), promiseB()]).then(([resultA, resultB])=>{ }) 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Answering the Question Asked**

This is the correct way to sequence or chain Promises:

```
one(arr).then(two).then(log, fail);
```

This directly answers the question without offering other possible solutions.

Please note there are no side effects. The "scope" issue mentioned in the comments is absolutely avoided.

The sample snippet implements this:

```js
let arr = [];

function one(arr) {
  return new Promise((res, rej) => {
    arr.push('one');
    res(arr);
  });
}
function two(arr) {
  return new Promise((res, rej) => {
    arr.push('two');
    res(arr);
  });
}

function log(arr){
  console.log(arr);
}

function fail(reason){
  console.log(reason);
}



one(arr).then(two).then(log, fail);
```